# Is there a way to use a colorWithPatternImage with the CCLabelTTF?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0, cclabelttf

I tried the following:

```
UIColor *c = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"gradient.png"]];
CCColor *cc = [CCColor colorWithUIColor: c];
lblLevelName = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: @"Level" fontName: @"" fontSize: 18.0f];
lblLevelName.anchorPoint = ccp(1.0f, 1.0f);
lblLevelName.position = ccp(screen.width - 20.0f, screen.height - 75.0f);
lblLevelName.fontColor = cc;
[self addChild: lblLevelName];
```

But I get a black label, while the gradient image was from yellow to orange.
Any suggestion?